# each wifi network validation except password cordova wifi

Tags: cordova-plugins, wifi

I have developed the wifi application using wifiwizard and cordova for android devices and it works fine. I can choose the network and I can put the password and I can validate it and connect into it. But the problem is my company got some extra validations like identity number, employee type, and some other details. So how am I suppose to do these stuffs or how to add these for particular networks. I have uploaded my entire wifi application which works exactly I expected. Please have a look and help me to do it still better.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <title>Wifi Wizard</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class = "content">   
                <table id = "displayNetworks" class = "table-responsive">

                </table>
      </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var unique_array = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android|BlackBerry)/)){
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }else{
        onDeviceReady();
    }
});

function onDeviceReady(){
    alert("I'm into the browser for debug");
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        WifiWizard.setWifiEnabled(true, win_enable, fail_enable);
    }, 200);
}

function win_enable(){
    alert("Wifi Enabled successfully");
}

function fail_enable(e){
    alert(e.message);
}

window.setTimeout(function(){ alert("I'm in here");
        WifiWizard.startScan(success_scan, fail_scan);
}, 1000);


function success_scan(){ alert("Trying to connect scan function");
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        getScanResult();
    }, 2000);
}

function fail_scan(e){
    alert(e.message);
}

function getScanResult(){alert("Im here too getting the scan result");
    WifiWizard.getScanResults(listHandler, fail_network);
}

function listHandler(a){
    alert(JSON.stringify(a));
    var network_array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
        network_array.push(a[i].SSID);
    }
    unique_array = network_array.filter(function(elem, pos){
        return network_array.indexOf(elem) == pos;
    });
    alert(network_array);
    var content = "<table>"
     for(var j = 0; j < network_array.length; j++){
          content += '<tr class="dynamicTable"><td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="clickWifi(\'' + network_array[j] + '\');">' + network_array[j] + '</a></td></tr>';
     }
     content += "</table>"
     document.getElementById('displayNetworks').innerHTML = content;
}

function fail_network(e){
    alert(e.message);
}

function clickWifi(netssid){ alert("Hello Im inside click function");
    var id = netssid;
    alert(id);
    var promptWindow = prompt("Please enter the password for the network: " + id);
    alert(promptWindow);
    var connectWifi = WifiWizard.formatWPAConfig(id, promptWindow);
        WifiWizard.addNetwork(connectWifi, function(){
            WifiWizard.connectNetwork(id, connectSuccess, connectFailed);
        });
}

function connectSuccess(e){
    alert("Connected Successfully");
    window.open("http://www.google.com", "_self");
}

function connectFailed(e){
    alert(e.message);
}
```

And too I'm having problem with window.open in the function connectSuccess, the window.open is not working inside my application and if I come out of my application I can reach Google.

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.wifiexpandables353717" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>WifiExpandables</name>
  <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
  <author email="you@example.com" href="http://example.com.com/">
      Your Name Here
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="2000"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: add the following lines in your config.xml and try once. <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>

Comment: Its working. thanks

Comment: Posted the answer. Please accept the answer if it was useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines in config.xml. It should work fine.

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
   <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
   <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
   <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```