# Ajax Call is not worked in mobile device using IONIC

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I have created the ionic app , I am running the app in browser is working fine . but the same app I tried to run in mobile the AJAX call is not working. Before the ajax i made alert it is populated. Below is my code .

Code is,

```
$http({
        method: 'POST', 
        //url: syncURL,
        url:"http://45.xx.xxx:8080/MobileSync/SummaTest/update_SummaNoun",
        data: surveyResultrecords,//surveyResultrecords 
         }).then(function(result){
                            console.log( "yay---" +JSON.stringify(result.data));
                            alert("yay");
                            alert("APTAM");
                                            //$scope.SummaNoun.id = surveyResultrecords.id;  
                                            //var promise1 = imageUpload(); 
                                            //console.log("PUSH completed ");
                                            //alert("test---finished");
                                            return "data Updated";//imageUpload();

                        }).then(function(ress){
                                console.log("PUSH completed ");
                                alert("push completed")
                        });
```

These are the cordova plugins i Installed ,

```
"cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-camera",
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-file",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer"
  ]
```

**Config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.Testcamera10008" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
  <name>testCamera</name>
  <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>
  <author email="you@example.com" href="http://example.com.com/">
      Your Name Here
    </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000"/>
  <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="2000"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="*"/>
    <allow-navigation href="*"/>
    <access origin="*"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy">
    <title>Testcamera</title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script><script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic-datepicker/dist/ionic-datepicker.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/controllers/AplicationLevelCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/controllers/SummaTest.js"></script>
    <script src="app/js/controllers/SummaNoun_Default_Activity.js"></script>

<body ng-app="Testcamera">
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</html>
```

Chrome Inspecter Image
[image: Chrome Inspecter for that ajax call worked in Browser for your reference]

I installed the cordova-whitelist plugin also my cordova version 6.2.0 , ionic 1.7.16.

Comment: Are you using Ionic live-server? It may be an CORS issue, you should look into that. Also use the chrome inspector in the network tab, to see if your request have some response headers.

Comment: we enabled the CORS in our serve also I am not accessing the ionic live server. can i show my config.xml is that help you to find the probs bro

Comment: You may edit your question adding anything you find relevant. What are your `<access>` and `<allow-navigation>` tags on the config.xml file?

Comment: `<access origin="*"/>` and `<allow-navigation href="*"/>` this is am using my config.xml`

Comment: hi , @ItaloAyres is there anything wrong in my .xml file

Comment: Yes, this seems to be fine, but the placement is odd. They usually are outside <platform name="android"> tag, along with the preferences, so both platforms will inherit from it. I also use `<allow-navigation href="http://*/*"/>` It may do some difference.
`

Comment: yes man, we tried what you have mentioned in `<allow-navigation href="http://*/*"/>` we got the same thing , Ajax call not called .

Comment: No clue, unfortunately. What about chrome network inspector. Provide more info about your server.

Comment: @ItaloAyres for your reference i added the image of that ajax call worked in chrome inspecter . I am not getting any clue is it possible to make this question to primary or highlight for every other stack over followers ?

Comment: This printscreen is from when you executed the app in the actual device? Because the request origin is a local ionic server. You should open the chrome device inspector **while** running the app in the device.

Comment: @SakthiSureshAnand Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158255/each-wifi-network-validation-except-password-cordova-wifi?noredirect=1#comment63796340_38158255 this should work

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't have plug-ins declaration in your config.xml, for example:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.2" />
```

And you don't have this tag:

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
```

[read here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/) for more informations about it

Also, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506957/ajax-call-on-cordova-ios-securityerror-dom-exception-18/31714491#31714491) may help you. Good luck

Comment: We tried the above also  but its not working . If you know any other way to overcome that probs

Comment: did you modify the config.xml file and add plug-ins declaration ? Because this configuration is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't need extra `then` in your code since it's not returning promise. It's just a string literal. Always handle error part of a promise.

Better version:

```
$http.post(url, data)
  .then(function (res){ // handles response
    console.log(res.data); // or execute success function
  }, function (err){ // handles error
    console.log(err); // or JSON.stringify(err) if it shows [object] on the console
  });
```

Make sure all the plugins are there on `platforms/(android/ios)` run on the device.

After that, do `ionic run android/ios --lc` and see error logs on command line to see what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible issue with white-listing. That's the reason the AJAX call may be working fine in browser and not in devices. You gotta use allow-intent attribute with proper settings for HTTP and HTTPS protocols in config.xml to get away from this problem.

Suggest you to check out this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158255/each-wifi-network-validation-except-password-cordova-wifi?noredirect=1#comment63796340_38158255) which has the desired settings to overcome this problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the kind response guys , we found the issue followed  @Italo Ayres his comment **Remote Debugging Android Devices** . we saw the log of our app and corrected the Error.

Because We tried Android Studio to see the logs but it doesn't shown that Ajax Call it shown only  before the AJAX call logs .

We referred this Link to see the mobile Logs using Chrome .Please have a look in it . Its very Usefull. [Remote Debugging Android Devices](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en)